# Por que não podemos sugerir edições em perguntas e respostas?

Tags: debate, edição, meta

Percebi que só posso editar meus próprios posts. A [página de privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) diz que poderei editar qualquer post com 500 pontos de reputação, mas imaginei que antes disso eu poderia ao menos sugerir edições.

No momento, vejo o link de editar habilitado em perguntas no site principal, e desabilitado nos seguintes casos:

- Respostas no site principal
- Perguntas no meta
- Respostas no meta

Por que não podemos sugerir edições em respostas dos outros? E por que não podemos sugerir edições em perguntas do meta?

Aliás, também não vejo o link de "review" neste site, talvez o motivo seja que o sistema de review ainda não está localizado. É isso?

Comment: Eu recebi sugestões para edição em uma pergunta minha já... Mas não acho onde fazer.

Comment: É, também estou sentindo falta da edição. Acho que é um recurso muito importante para mantermos experts no SOPT.

Comment: @MarcoAurélio, olhando novamente, percebi que as perguntas têm o link de editar (exceto no meta), mas as respostas, não.